# Approval workflow for SharePoint pages(classic site/pages) using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, power-automate

I would like to create and approval similar to this

[Link](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-for-sharepoint-pages-using-power-automate/)

Would i be able to use the same for a classic site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

Page approval flows are currently available on SharePoint communication sites and modern team sites only.

In classic site, you could use OOB feature Content Approval via Library Settings>Versioning Settings>Select "Yes" for "Require content approval for submitted items?"

Or use SharePoint designer workflow to control content approval.

For more information, please refer to:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/require-approval-of-items-in-a-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EACAAA=Classic

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-page-approval-using-power-automate-14ce6976-a0a7-427b-b4ab-d28d344a5222